# Import data from website (javascript table) to excel

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am trying to import data from a specific website using a macro, but I've been unsuccessful, I believe that's because the table is in JavaScript.

Does anyone have a code to do the above?

The website: "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig/results/"

The aim is to import the table with the games/results/odds.

Comment: What have you already tried? can you show some code here?

Comment: Hi SuperDJ, no to be honest I am not expert... I saw here some code but only work for a different website... don't work for the site that I told above...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Javascript to read a simple table online to excel why you not use power query? download from it :

https://www.microsoft.com/it-IT/download/details.aspx?id=39379

After install select power query tab on excel and from web as source of power query :

[image]

Insert your website :

[image]

and select the table that you want to import :

[image]

is more easy than javascript